# What's the best way to pass a variable to layout.php in Symfony?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

All pages of the website I'm working on will show a signin form.

I'd like to display this form in layout.php so it appears everywhere.

I'm not sure what's the best way to do this.

Should I use a filter?

I don't think using a slot is efficient since content won't change throughout the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A filter doesnt actually make much sense - in fact weve jsut gotten rid of a similar filters for things in the head have we not?? :-)

A slot is the reccommended way to pass things up to layout.php. However you could just use a partial and/or component directly in the layout with `include_partial` or `include_component` respectively.

Comment: Alright I used a component in that case which made more sense. works great, thanks. I don't know where the documentation is for 1.4 though. Doc for 1.2 is still working though: http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_sub_components

Comment: @Guillaume: The book is for "The Diffinitive Guide" book. As far as i know thats been deprecated for 1.3/1.4 and instead there is "Practial Symfony" (this is essentially the jobeet book - similar to askeet), "Symfony Reference Guide" - basically just an API reference with additional detail beyond standard API docs and "More with Symfony" which is an advanced book that goes through implementation of more advanced things. However, having said that youre going to wan to also look at the Propel documentation for things like your inital question.